# AVD emulator error in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm a newbie, my problem is when I try to make a new AVD I get this message :

"an error occurred while creating the avd. see idea.log for details"

I just downloaded android studio , dunno what to do

this is from the log file : unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI x86 to copy into the avd folder

Comment: his error can also pop out when there is no disk space

Answer (score 14):

**If you are in linux, try this:**

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

It worked for me!

Comment: windows actualy

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I wish I could upvote multiple times. Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

You pasted `x86_64` file inside the default folder

```
C:\Users\(User Name)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-29\default
```

Past it in `android-29` folder not in `default` folder.

Answer (score 0):

On windows:

1. Used 'Clone Device' option on device definition, it will add new device into list with appending '(edited)1' string.
2. select this clone device: press 'Next'
3. select this clone device: press 'Next'
4. select system image as per your requirement: press 'Next'
5. select 'Show Advance Setting' scroll down: in 'Memory and Storage' choose 'External file' (which is disable/gray-out in actual device but available in clone device) keep entry empty.
6. press 'Finish'

Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and after trying @Tiago Elias's answer, I got passed that stage but ran into another problem whereby the emulator could not launch. Surprisingly, all of these where happening because I did not install the *Android Emulator* from SDK Tools. To do this,

**Open the SDK Manager**
[image]

**Select the SDK Tools tab**, If Android Emulator is unchecked, then **check it and click on OK**.
[image]

You can now create a new emulator and run your app in it.

Answer (score 0):

There might be several reason for this error, but this solution worked for me:

Go to your avd location "C:\Users.android\avd", delete all the files inside this, and create the AVD Emulators once again from the Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Update for latest Android 2021 September - on Windows i deleted the SDK and reinstalled it, that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

when avd runs gradle build is running sudden error occured that:
Darkaction bar theme is not found and resource linking failed.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32495819)