# Unable to create an Android virtual machine using Android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, bios

On Android studio When I tried to create Android virtual Device(AVD)

Following message was showing:

> "an error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details."

I am in 64 bit Windows 8.1.
Here is a screen shot of the problem
[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55662531/4582111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[solved]
VTx was disabled in my BIOS. 
Had to enable that.

Answer (score 6):

This happens because of Space issue . Please free some space from your C drive or from the drive where your virtual device will be stored

Also please close the window of UIautomationviewer/SDK module which are open

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but in Linux. The cause of trouble in my case was the SD Card so I choose the option "external file" change of "studio-managed".
[image: Configuration of AVD]

I found some help in this post [How to find the logs on android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784877/how-to-find-the-logs-on-android-studio).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55662440/4582111