# impossible to create emulator with android studio

Tags: android

I have a problem with the android studio emulator. When I try to create the emulator I got the following message:

> ERROR CREATIN AVD, an error occured while creating the avd, see idea.log.details

I followed the recommendations for the configuration of the emulator.
What could be the reason for this error?

My configuration: I have a MacBook Air 2014 and OS x El Capitan (10.11.6)
I choose X86 or X84_64

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to paste the content of file **idea.log**. The file could be found under android studio folder.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Developers website has a comprehensive and detailed tutorial on how to properly set up your emulator. Please follow the tutorial below as well as my suggestions for success:

- Make sure you have the latest version of android studio installed
- On the top menu, select Help -> Check for Update and install any new updates that the IDE recommends.
- The following command worked for a Linux user encountering the same issue. It is worth a shot, but I doubt that is the reason for your error: `sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6`

Perhaps you didn't install android studio properly and you are missing some plugin for the AVD. To be `100%` sure, follow the below tutorials from Android on how to properly set-up your AVD.

References

- https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html
- https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html
- [AVD emulator error in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43105314/avd-emulator-error-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

your HAXM is not enable

pls enable it from bios

go to Bios-> find Intel Virtual Technology-> Enable

Answer (score 0):

i find this : he say go the terminal (mac os) and paste : sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features

I think we have targeted the problem. I made the recommendations (make this copy paste in the terminal), I checked that the option was activated in my SDK, always this damn error ...

The bios for mac os (from the internet it is not accessible).

thank you